# Is there anywhere where there are in-depth walkthroughs of problems on Stewart's Calculus?

Tags: calculus

I'm currently taking calc 2 and using Stewart's calculus. My major qualms with the book is the lack of examples. On a scale of 1-10, the practice problems in the chapters are like 1-3, then the example problems are all very difficult without walkthroughs at the end of the book. I'm struggling to figure out where I went wrong when I get a wrong answer. Is there any site which aggregates in-depth solutions of difficult problems?

I'm currently on arc-lengths and surface area, and I keep getting crazy integrals which I have no idea how to solve. For example, I I've recently gotten $∫\sqrt{(1+cos^2)}$, $∫\sqrt{(1+(1-1/x)^2}$. I'm not sure if I'm just setting up the problems wrong, or what...

I got $∫\sqrt{(1+cos^2)}$ from y = $\sin x$ and $∫\sqrt{(1+(1-1/x)^2}$ from y = x - $\ln{x}$.

Comment: Welcome to MS. Please typeset your mathematics using LaTex . Read here   https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!